# remove characters from a list of strings in python

Tags: python, string, list, conditional-statements, erase

I have a list of strings that contain a url plus some other words.
The URL looks like this: `<a href="https://www.blabla/k20832">`
I was wondering if there is a way to tell python to delete everything inside the `<>`.

I was using this to delete other words:

```
list = [w.replace('hello', '') for w in list]
```

Comment: you want to delete everything inside of <>? not just certain characters?

Comment: delete everything inside the <>? are you sure?

Comment: yes everything inside the <> keeping the <> would be nice but also not necessary

Comment: If there is no other way (i strongly believe there is since my proposal is not efficient in any way) - you can just loop through string and check every symbol if it's "<" and remove every symbol until you hit ">".

Comment: `regex` will handle this nicely: select a string section and filter that substring.

Comment: `re.sub("\<.*?\>","",msg)`

Comment: thanks Joran, I put that in a loop and worked perfctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

```
import re
str = "<a href=\"https://www.blabla/k20832\"> word1 word2"
str2 = re.sub('<a.*?>', ' ', str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find function.

```
str = '< a href="https://www.blabla/k20832 > word1 word2'

start_Index=str.find('<')

end_Index=str.find('>')

print(str[:start_Index+1]+str[end_Index:])
```